# Trying to modify const data: Compile error: passing 'const Device::FFT' as 'this' argument of 'void Device::FFT::DataBEtoLE()' discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, class, oop, constants, endianness

I have a data array which is populated from the network device in big endian format. The processor on the host is an intel processor, therefore by default little endian.

I have written a member function (`DataBEtoLE`) inside a class named `FFT` of which is wrapped in a namespace named `Device` of which converts the `data` array recieved from the network device to the byte order (little endian) on the host.

`processBufferData` receives a `const void* data` array of which is parsed and then processed within `Device::Message`. What I then want to do is take the data received and convert it from little endian to big endian which is what the `DataBEtoLE` function does.

However, when trying to compile the following (simplified) code, I recieve the following error:

```
Compile error: passing 'const Device::FFT' as 'this' argument of 'void Device::FFT::DataBEtoLE()' discards qualifiers
```

I suspect this has something to do with a `const` conflict as the message being recieved is a const, and I am trying to modify that, but I am not sure how to get around this.

My code is as follows:

```c++
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;
namespace Device {
    class FFT {
        private:
            uint16_t data[16384];

        public:
            void DataBEtoLE() {
                for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]); i++){
                    data[i] = ntohs(data[i]);
                }
            }
    };

    union Message {
        FFT fft;
    };
}

void FFTProcessor (const Device::Message& message);

void processBufferData (const void* data) {
    const Device::Message* message = (const Device::Message*)data;

    message->fft.DataBEtoLE();     // compile error is here
    FFTProcessor(*message);
}

void FFTProcessor (const Device::Message& message) {    
    // do stuff with modified device data here
}

int main(){
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[16384];

    processBufferData(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't compile. Please extract and provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have modified the code to compile. Note that it only successfully compiles if you comment `message->fft.DataBEtoLE();` as this is where the code fails to compile.

Comment: Why is the received data `const`? And is it actually a `Device::Message`? (And why is `Message` a union with just one member?)

Comment: @molbdnilo regarding the consts - that part of it is code from an sdk implemented onto our processor. It is receiving raw data from the device that must remain constant for the sanity of the program. There are 3 more members within that union, but they are irrelevant to this excerpt.

Comment: Then the existence of the union is also irrelevant. If the underlying data is const, and thus must not be modified, you have no other option than to work with a copy.

Comment: What do you think that function does that you're trying to call? That code is indeed far from a [mcve], btw. `foo const f; f.mutating_function();` is the gist of it, plus some boilerplate.